# Find 1, 2, 3 missing numbers in an array of first N natural numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assuming an array is sorted, how would you find 1, 2, and 3 missing numbers in an array of the first N natural numbers?

Again, assuming the array is sorted, the following code will work for returning one value that is missing (due to the `return` statement)

```
    function findMissingNumbers(array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] != (i + 1)) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
        return 'no missing numbers found';
    }

    var missingArr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    console.log(findMissingNumbers(missingArr));
```

I have seen many responses that do the same (find one missing value) by taking the sum and the expected sum and finding the missing value by subtracting the sum from the expected sum however, this too will only find one missing value.

I know that this code will not work by using i as I am-- I tried to write it by pushing the missing values into a new array if arr[i] != i + 1, but again, this will only return the correct value for the first missing value.

How would you approach this problem?

Comment: you could change the return type to array and rethink your condition

Comment: i think you are right here by assuming if its a sorted array of natural numbers; a[i]==i implies we havent run into any cases where you have a missing number.    To make this optimal, i would consider a binary search, finding the first time a[i]!=i  identifying the missing number there and then continuing the search (you would need to change your search criteria as you go, because the different between a[i] and i would vary based on where you are in array).  Using a b-search would make it so you dont have to check every item. For your explicit question - i would just change the return type

Comment: Why would pushing the missing natural numbers to an array only "return the correct value for the first value"? What does it even mean?

Comment: if you have an array starting with "4", are you looking to have 1, 2, and 3 in your result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find minimum and maxium number in array, create array from them using `Array.from()` filter that array with provided array to return missing numbers.

```js
 function findMissingNumbers(arr) {
  var min = Math.min(...arr);
  var max = Math.max(...arr);
  var all = Array.from(Array(max - min + 1), (e, i) => i + min)
  return all.filter(e => !arr.includes(e))
 }

 console.log(findMissingNumbers([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
  console.log(findMissingNumbers([10, 16, 8]));
```

Comment: This works, and has the advantage that it doesn't even require the input to be sorted.  But it also doesn't take advantage of the fact that it's sorted and is presumably much less efficient for larger lists, `O(n^2)` versus `O(n)`.

Comment: Great solution. Didn't consider using the Math and filter methods.

Comment: Just noticed, shouldn't the second console log include numbers 1 through 9 instead of just 9?

Comment: It finds missing numbers from minimum to maximum numbers in array so no.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'd be curious how to take advantage of the fact that it's sorted with this.

Comment: @Nol: I don't think there's a way to combine this with a technique that takes advantage of sorting.  See answers from guest271314 or Ant for examples that do use the sorting.  You'd have to choose between elegant code and efficient code depending on the requirements you have.  If I was dealing with 100 entries, this elegant code would win in my mind.   If I had millions of them, I'd have to think about the more efficient versions.

Comment: Ant's answer has been deleted.  But Agalo's and others also look efficient.

Answer (score 3):

One more implementation that should work. It should be `O(n)` in terms of time complexity.

```js
function findMissingNumbers(array) {
     var missingNumbers = [];
     var endInteger = array[array.length - 1];
  var missingNumberCounter = 0;
  
        for (var i=0; i < endInteger; i++) {
            if (array[i - missingNumberCounter] != (i + 1)) {
                missingNumbers.push(i + 1);
  missingNumberCounter++;
            }
        }
        return missingNumbers;
        
    }

var missingArr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var missingArr2 = [2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11];
console.log(findMissingNumbers(missingArr));
console.log(findMissingNumbers(missingArr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make two changes here.

1. Returning an array from your function instead of returning the number within the first iteration of your for loop.
2. Create a new variable to keep track of those numbers that have been missed.

Below is the updated code snippet:

```
function findMissingNumbers(array) {
    var resultsArray = [];
    var missedNumbers = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var expectedValue = i + 1 + missedNumbers;

        if (array[i] != expectedValue) {
            var segmentCountOfMissedNumbers = array[i] - expectedValue;

            for (var ii = 0; ii < segmentCountOfMissedNumbers; ii++) {
                resultsArray.push(expectedValue + ii);
            }
            missedNumbers = missedNumbers + segmentCountOfMissedNumbers;
        }
    }

    if (resultsArray.length > 0) {
        return resultsArray;
    } else {
        return 'no missing numbers found';
    }
}

var missingArr = [3, 5, 9];
console.log(findMissingNumbers(missingArr));
```

Comment: this solution is assuming that there can be only one missing number between two entries of the array. [1,2,5] would report only [3] as missing, while it should report [3,4]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`, `do..while` loop

```js
var missingArr = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9];
var res = [];

missingArr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  var i = a + 1;
  if (i !== b) {
    do { 
      res.push(i++) 
    } while (i < b);
  }
  return b
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
function* findMissingNumbers(array) {
    var numbers = new Set(array),
        i = 1;

    while (numbers.size) {
        if (numbers.has(i)) {
            numbers.delete(i);
        } else {
            yield i;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

console.log([...findMissingNumbers([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])]);
console.log([...findMissingNumbers([6, 7])]);
console.log([...findMissingNumbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an(other) non-ES6 solution.  The inner loop could probably be reworked to not require sorting as the next to last line.

Regardless of the inner loop it should at worst run in O(n) x 2 vis a vis an array bounded by 1 and the max value of the array -- the inner loop is only run more than once to find more than one "gaps".

Maybe the loop is less elegant than [this non-ES6 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42072411/find-1-2-3-missing-numbers-in-an-array-of-first-n-natural-numbers/42073137#42073137), but on the other hand mine has the advantage of not introducing any variables other than the array that gets returned.

```
function findMissingNumbers(array) {
    var missingNumbers = [];

    for (var i=0, n=array.length; i<n; i++) {
        if (array[i] > (i + 1 + missingNumbers.length)) {
            for (j=1, k = array[i] - (i + 1 + missingNumbers.length); j<=k; j++) {
                missingNumbers.push(array[i] - j);
            }
        }
    }

    missingNumbers.sort();
    return missingNumbers;
}

var missingArr = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9];
console.log(findMissingNumbers(missingArr).join(",")); //2,3,8
```